# In MATLAB How to calculate a time between two dates with a custom format?

Tags: matlab, datetime, datetime-format

I have two dates with bellow format and want to calculate the time between these times:

```
 t1=datestr(clock,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS:FFF');
 t2=datestr(clock,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS:FFF');
```

My output should be in this format:

```
 (YY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS:FFF)
```

as an example
      (0:0:1:2:3:44:25:330)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can first convert the t1 and t2 char arrays to numeric format
>   using datenum() function then you can calculate the difference between
>   the calculated numeric dates back to the required format using
>   datestr() function.

The code illustrating the procedure is given below.

```
% storing the two times
t1=datestr(clock,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS:FFF')
t2=datestr(clock,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS:FFF')

% convertine the stored times to numeric format
% using datenum()
numeric_t1 = datenum(t1, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS:FFF');
numeric_t2 = datenum(t2, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS:FFF');

% calculating the time difference
time_diff = datestr((numeric_t2 - numeric_t1), 'yy:mm:dd:HH:MM:SS:FFF')
```

**Command Window Output**

[image]

Comment: Good answer but why did you need to put a picture of the console output ??

Comment: Just for verification.

Comment: That's good. I meant you could have simply copy/pasted the text

Comment: Actually, I work for someone and there it is necessary to show and post the output screenshots that's why I have a tendency to post the output window. :)